Can't put specific folder on quick access on Windows 11
Using Windows 11. I like to put my most used folders on quick access bar on Explorer, it's very convenient.
But i have a specific folder, that Windows won't let to fix it. I can drag the folder to quick access, Windows will show me the 'Pin to quick access' icon , but when i drop it, nothing happens !

The issue happens only for this specific folder, but for my bad luck, it's my most used folder... The folder has not in special, i can put any folder there, except this one.
Anything i could do ?
Thanks

It worked, thank you ! Please post as solution

done. (And may Delphi object Pascal live long and prosper.)

Sometimes drag-and-drop operations fail in Windows. Use an alternate method when that happens,  Right-click on an item, and select Pin to Quick access.

Note that not all types of objects can be pinned to Quick access, in which case that option will not chow in the context menu.
Also, issues with drag-and-drop sometimes are fixed simply by rebooting, or, faster, press CtrlAltDel, select Sign out, then sign back in to restart Explorer.
